# Machine learning : Predict output number from input vector trained "matched"

Tags: php, python, math, machine-learning

I would know if its possible in maths to predict output number from multiple samples given with input vectors.

I really dont know how to explain this so I will give you an example :
The vector will be like [hours studied, sleep hours] and output is the score at a school test :

```
x.train(100, [5, 8])
x.train(0, [0, 0])
x.predict([2.5, 4]) // should return 50 (because inputs are the half)
x.predict([5, 8]) // should return 100
x.predict([0, 0]) // should return 0
```

Sorry if I am not clear enought .. If you can understand what I mean do you know a Python or PHP library that can do that and an example of how to use it ?

Thank you very much and have a great day !

Comment: Neural Network may help you. See example: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/stephencwelch/Neural-Networks-Demysitifed/blob/master/Part%207%20Overfitting%2C%20Testing%2C%20and%20Regularization.ipynb

Comment: do you know [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/)?

Comment: I believe simple 2 var regression could do that. You can implment this in any language, not that complicated. http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Reg2IV.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `scikit-learn` you can do:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit([[5, 8], [0 , 0]], [100, 0])

print(clf.predict([[2.5, 4], [5, 8], [0, 0]]))
```

You should be aware of the chance of [over/underfitting](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html). You might want to consider using [polynomial features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) which would increase the complexity of your model and thus increasing the change of better prediction but don't pick too complex features (in this case high polynomial degree) since it would surely lead you to overfitting. Try to find a trade-off between the two by using [cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

Consider also using [Ridge](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge) or [Lasso](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso) which natively deal with overfitting.

Comment: Just a question .. Is it possible to make it "non-linear" ?

Comment: Linear in LinearRegression refers to the weights which will be learned. As mentioned above by adding polynomial features, such as x^2 you get a non-linear fit through your data.

Comment: @EyeSalut just as `desiato` said use the [polynomial features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) mentioned above. [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html#example-linear-model-plot-polynomial-interpolation-py) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html) there are examples how to used them.